# Velocity: "Lexical error" with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, velocity

I'm developing a web application using Apache Velocity and encountered a lexical error that said "Lexical error, Encountered: "(" (40), after : "".

The error was brought about by codes that included "JavaScript" like the following.

```
<script>
  function getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
  }
  $var = window;
  $var.alert(getHelloWorld());
</script>
```

Avoiding that error, I tried the code below and got a result as expected.

```
<script>
  $var = window;
  helloworld = "Hello World!";
  $var.alert(helloworld);
</script>
```

I wondered if you could tell me the reason as in detail as possible.

Thank you.

Takahiro,

Comment: This: _'Encountered: "(" (40), after : "".'_ makes me wonder if there's any illegal (non-rendering) characters in your code.
Can you delete that last line (`$var.alert(getHelloWorld());`), and re-type it, manually?

Comment: Thank you for helping so much. I tried your advice but the same error occurred. There seem to be complex reasons beyond my knowledge :/ Anyway, thanks a lot!